# Exclude all lines with specific lower case characters in unix text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file which has combination of lower/upper characters. I want to remove lines where any of a few specific lowercase letters are seen.

Text file contents:

```
aASDF1234qwerty;lkJHG
fdsaAghiyirchgdadgqa2
```

Task - Remove all lines where any of the lowercase characters 'a','e','j','k' occurs.

I tried below option to get all lines where only upper case are found but its not working as expected. `grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*A*E*J*K*[[:alnum:]]*' test.txt`

Comment: You might want to read about the `-v` option in the `grep` man page.

Comment: All of the given lowercase letters must be on the line, or any of them?

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  What have you tried so far for your homework ?

Comment: I tried below option to get all lines where only upper case are found but its not working as expected. 

    grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*A*E*J*K[[:alnum:]]*' test.txt

Comment: Jeff, any of them

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -v '[aejk]' /path/to/file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '! /[aejk]/ { print }' /path/to/file
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/[aejk]/d' /path/to/file
```

The regular expression used in all of these examples, `/[aejk]/`, can be transliterated to mean "any character of: `a`, `e`, `j`, or `k`".  The `grep` and `awk` invocations return any line which does *not* match that expression; the `sed` invocation has the same end result, but works by *omitting* from the parsed file any lines which *do* match.

Comment: hi DopeGhoti, aejk is not a string but individual characters. so I want to scan each of this individual letters in entire file and  remove the lines where combination of this charcters are all lower case.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's what the brackets do.  When you search for [aejk] you are searching for a, e, j, and/or, k.  Not for "aejk".  You can test it at: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please clarify in your question: Are you looking to exclude any line in which _any_ of these lower case letters appear, or in which _all_ of them appear in that specific sequence?

Comment: He wants to remove the lines where any of those characters appear, but that is what your answer does isn't it?  It seemed to work for me when I tested the regex.

Comment: That is indeed precisely what my proposed answer does.

Comment: Actually rereading his comment I think he may want to remove lines that contain ALL of those characters in lowercase but not in any specific order.

Comment: Hence the request for clarification one way or the other.

Comment: He already clarified on the question.  He wrote, "Jeff, any of them."

Comment: @Wildcard, yes that's what I initially thought too but his comment on this answer contradicts that:  `I want to scan each of this individual letters in entire file and remove the lines where combination of this charcters are all lower case. `

Comment: @Jesse_b, ah.  Oh well, this answer matches the question as currently edited.  ;)  If he wants to clarify he can.

Comment: To select lines where all characters do appear, seem like awk is the correct (and simple) solution:  `awk '/a/&&/e/&&/j/&&/k/' file`.